# Defective items in a bag

Tags: probability

Can anyone help me in these questions:

I am not sure if I am doing it in the right way.

A bag contains 20 items with  5 defective items.

Items are sampled at random one at a time. What is the probability that the 3rd and 4th
defectives found occur at the 5th and 6th sample draws if

a)The items are replaced after each is drawn?

I did:

5 defective items and 15 non defective then:

The probability  that the 3rd and 4th defectives found occur at the 5th and 6th is:

$(\frac{1}{18})^4 . (\frac{5}{20})^2 $

b) The items are not replaced after each is drawn?

Because the items are not replaced I think that we only need to be worry about the last two items that need to be defective

But I am not sure because for the last two it can be $\frac{5}{5} and \frac{4}{4}$ for the rest we need to decrease also the number of items. So it will be

probability = $ \frac{18}{18}.\frac{17}{17}.\frac{16}{16}.\frac{15}{15}.\frac{5}{5}.\frac{4}{4}$

Can anyone let me know if this is correct?

Thank you

Comment: To clarify:  there are $20$ items in total?  $5$ defective, $15$ good?  Assuming that:  then for part a. you first need exactly $2$ of the first four draws to be defective and then you need the next two to be defective.  That's $\binom 42 \left(\frac 5{20}\right)^2\left(\frac {15}{20}\right)^2\left(\frac 5{20}\right)^2$

Comment: yes in total there are 20 items, where 5 are defectives and 15 are good.

Comment: I do not understand what you did, can you explain it better? thanks

Comment: I'll post some details below.

Answer (score 1):

For part $a$:

In order to get the third and fourth defective draws on the fifth and sixth trials we need two things to happen.  First of all, we need the first four draws to contain exactly two defective units.   Secondly, we need the fifth and sixth draws to both be defective.

For the first:  the probability that a given draw is defective is $p=\frac 5{20}$.  We are faced with a standard Bernoulli process so the probability of getting exactly two "successes" out of four trials is $$\binom 42p^2(1-p)^2=\binom 42 \left(\frac 5{20}\right)^2\left(\frac {15}{20}\right)^2$$

For the second:  the probability that two specified draws are both defective is $p^2$.  Thus the final answer is $$\binom 42p^2(1-p)^2p^2=\binom 42\left(\frac 5{20}\right)^2\left(\frac {15}{20}\right)^2\left(\frac 5{20}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

b) You want exactly 2 defective items among the 4 first ones you pick up. The number of sets of 4 different items you can pick up is $ \binom{20}{4}$, and the number of sets of 4 different items among which 2 are defective is $ \binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{15}{2} $. This gives a probability of picking two defective items in your four first picked items of

$\frac{\binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{15}{2}}{\binom{20}{4}} $

Then, to pick two other defective items is to pick two specific items from three remainging $ \binom{3}{2}$, while the total number of sets of two items you can pick is $ \binom{16}{2}$. This gives, as final probability

$\frac{\binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{15}{2} \cdot \binom{3}{2}}{\binom{20}{4} \cdot \binom{16}{2}} $